# Difference between adding a user with the Net User command vs using Windows Credential Manager

Tags: command-line, printer, network-printer, windows-10-pro

Today I was working on a client who had a printer connected to PC-1 (running Windows 10 Pro) but they needed to print on it from PC-2. I set up a connection from PC-2 to PC-1 using the Windows Credential Manager so that the printer could be used from PC-2.

But I'm also aware that there is a command called Net User that would allow me to create a new username and password for that machine. Do these two methods achieve the same result, and if not, how do they differ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you created and stored a credential that authenticates a user on PC1 on PC2?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. The credentials are all finally stored in the
same place:

```
C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials
```

Whatever credentials are created by `net User` are later visible
in the Credential Manager.